# Shouldn’t deleted:1 return all deleted posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, deleted-answers, deleted-questions, search

According to [access to moderator tools](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> ## Viewing deleted posts
>
> You now have privileged access to posts that have been removed, either by their authors, by users with access to moderator tools, by moderators, or by the system.
>
> Use this privilege wisely:
>
> - Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team.
> - Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion.
> - Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post.
>
> You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.

The key words are in the final paragraph: **to find your *own* deleted posts**. Why is this limited to your own posts? Given that the whole point in seeing deleted posts is to ensure the feature is being used correctly, as delineated in the preceding paragraphs, shouldn’t you be able to use `deleted:1` to see *all* deleted posts, and then follow it up with, say, `user:me` to see your own?

This would have the added benefit that if there’s a problematic user with the ID `user:x`, you could search `deleted:1 user:x` and see how much trouble they’re stirring up behind the scenes.

Comment: Mods do have that power. IIRC even just this smaller version is a pretty recent addition to the 10K toolkit. Check M.SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently [asked this on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314208/346705), and it was [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314209/346705) by one of their mods over there. I’m really not sure why I didn’t post this sooner, but here it is.

> This is actually by design.
>
> The whole point of seeing deleted posts isn't really to ensure that the delete feature is being used correctly, so much as it gives high-reputation users the opportunity to find their older posts that have been deleted, which would be otherwise impossible.
>
> This search function works as you describe for moderators of a site, giving them access to all deleted posts, not just their own and the ability to limit results by user.
>
> Users with access to the 10k tools can actually see recently deleted posts using the deleted tab on the tools page. For the site you have 10k on, that's [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days). This allows you to view posts that have been deleted as long ago as 30 days. For review purposes, this should be sufficient.
>
> If you think that more detailed inspection is necessary, it's probably better left up to a moderator to handle, as any action would need to involve them, anyway.

As for my point in the question about looking up a user who’s causing trouble, a different mod commented on that question that:

> That is pretty much *exactly* why we don’t allow that. No one but a diamond moderator needs to be searching up a user’s history.

Whether we want this kind of policy to exist on our site individually or not should be left to the community. This is the “official” explanation as to why this is not implemented site-wide, and I suspect even if we get community approval to talk with the powers that be about implementing it here alone, perhaps on a test basis, I suspect that they would probably come back with a similar answer explaining why they’re not going to do that.